# SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found:

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, composer, laravel5

Добрый вечер, долго искал решение и до сих пор не нашел.

У меня есть готовый проект на Laravel 5.4, который я решил установить себе на Windows(OpenServer). При установке была сначала такая ошибка:

```
Warning: require(W:\domains\furypay\bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in W:\domains\furypay\bootstrap\autoload.php on line 17
Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'W:\domains\furypay\bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.;w:/modules/php/PHP-5.6-x64;w:/modules/php/PHP-5.6-x64/PEAR/pear') in W:\domains\furypay\bootstrap\autoload.php on line 17
```

Но я решил её прописав команду `composer update` в корне проекта.

Но при обновлении composer, в конце было написано:

```
In Connection.php line 647:
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'furypay.tickets' doesn't exist (SQL: select * from `tickets` where (`owner` is null and `status` = 0))

In Connection.php line 319:
 SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'furypay.tickets' doesn't exist

Script php artisan optimize handling the post-update-cmd event returned with error code 1
```

И этот текст появляется при командах `php artisan migrate` и подобных

Перепробовал уже многое, ничего не помогает, прошу помощи решения вот этой вот задачи у вас.

Answer (score 0):

Как пишет в сообщении в базе данных furypay не существует таблицы tickets. К которой идет обращение в миграциях. Возможно тебе нужна эта таблица тогда ее нужно будет внести в миграции. А возможно миграции неверные и нужно просто удалить все связано с этой таблицей. Смотри по коду что у тебя и как.

Comment: Мне пишет это при написании команды "php artistan migrate". Не запускается даже миграция

Comment: Поставь Xdebug, после поставь брекпоинт в файле Connection.php line 647: и поймеш проблему очень быстро.

Comment: Можно по подробнее? Я новичёк, что за брекпоинт?

Comment: слева будет debug_backtrace и по нему увидишь что и где не так

Comment: гугли xdebug phpstorm, видео на ютубе , статьи на хабре

Comment: дебагер тебе облегчит жызнь, разбирайся в нем даже неделю оно того стоит. И такие проблемы как эта будут решаться очень быстро

Comment: Я попробую с помощью его разобраться в этом

Comment: Как я понял, это проблемы не в самих файлах, а в проблемах с composer, может несовпадение версий или еще что-то.

Answer (score 0):

Тоже столкнулся с подобной проблемой при развёртывании приложения на хостинге, хотя на локальном сервере всё работало нормально.
Оказалось, что у меня в коде был `SELECT` из базы данных, который брал данные из таблицы `ARTISTS`. А в бд у меня таблица записана как `artists` (маленькими буквами). Возможно, это проблема MySQL (в моём случае), так как локально стоит 8 версия, а на хостинге 5.6.

Comment: у вас бд стоит под виндой, а на хостинге на иксах. Винда регистронезависима, а иксы - нет.